# Does Transmigrate soul transfer Ki, Psychic, and Magic abilities?

Tags: spells, anima-beyond-fantasy

If the spell Transmigrate Soul (*Anima* 153) succeeds, creature A's soul moves into creature B's body. With a good enough roll, creature A consumes creature B's soul. The spell then says that creature B keeps its physical attributes but replaces its mental attributes with those of creature A. If both creatures possessed different ki, psychic, and magical abilities, what abilities does creature B now have?

Answer (score 4):

There are many discussions about this spell and most people agree with the following statements. This is what would happen when you use that spell:

**Mental - Things you're keeping**

- Your Ki
- Your Psychic abilities
- Your Magical abilities
- Your attributes, related abilities and resistances:

  - INT, PER, POW, WP
- Almost everything you know
- Your experience (your combat abilities are yours)

**Mental - Things you're losing**

- The creature's mind and everything related to it
- The creature's experience (in combat, his knowledge...)

**Phsysical - Things you're keeping**

- A new body with all his physical advantages and disadvantages
- Special characteristics if the new body has them
- The creature's physical attributes, related abilities and resistances:

  - STR, AGI, DEX, CON

**Physical - Things you're losing**

- Your body (usually weaker) and everything related to it.

**Example**

You are a mage and you transmigrate your soul into a samurai's body successfully. Now you can use your spells and your ki as if nothing changed, but inside a strong and fit body. This samurai has a katana but, as you have never learned how to fight or how to use it, you can't because you don't know how. Your base attack and defense are still the same since that requieres experience.

Source: My own experience and a lot of research in Spanish forums.

Comment: This answer appears to duplicate the other answer to this question, but without any reference to back up its contention. I'm guessing you intended to point out something the other answer didn't, but I can't work out what - could you possibly edit it so as to make that point clearer?

Comment: Well, I wanted it to be a comment in the other answer to complement it, but I can't. And yes, I try to point out the physical part because it's not very clear in the first answer.

Comment: That's a significant improvement, so +1. (I recommend adding relevant rules citations and/or links to relevant pages on the Spanish fora, though.)

Answer (score 3):

In Anima, Ki,  Psychic and Magical powers all come from the soul of the individual.

The receptor will keep all his Ki, Psychic and Magical abilities.

You can find more in the official Anima forum (in Spanish), where this question has been asked multiple times and expands more in what can and what can't be done: 
[Official Site](http://www.edgeent.com/tema/65262-duda_transmigrar_alma/)

Unfortunately, there are no written rules for exactly what you can get and what you can't. Some masters change attack and defense values and other don´t (as it could be physical or it could be training and part of the donors 'muscle memory´).

I recommend you discuss it with your master/players before attempting this spell. Or not, that could be more fun :D